# linq to entities orderby

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

How can I convert this query to linq to entities with entity framework:

```
SELECT  customer_id,
    customer_name,
    customer_code
FROM dbo.V_STF_CUSTOMER
WHERE   company_id=@company_id AND
ORDER BY    CASE
            WHEN ISNUMERIC(customer_name)=1 THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END,
        customer_name
```

I have this:

```
return CUstomers.GetQuery().
            Where(x => x.CompanyId == companyId).
        OrderBy(??This is my problem??);
```

I don't know how to translate the orderby. Any idea?

Comment: you can use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions.isnumeric.aspx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
return Customers.GetQuery().
            Where(x => x.CompanyId == companyId).
        OrderBy(x=> SqlFunctions.IsNumeric(x.customer_name)).
        ThenBy(x=> x.customer_name);
```

Comment: @Oskar: I think we need to cast the result after Where() to an Enumerable? Then only Linq->EF will be able to work with the IsNumeric method! If I am not wrong, it should give an error saying, IsNumeric is not supported/translateable with Linq->Entities?

Comment: @System.ChaosException What do you mean? The "Where" returns an enumerable

Comment: @Oskar: I was under the impression that `Customers.GetQuery().Where()` would return an IQueryable<Customers>! Correct me if am wrong!

Comment: @System.ChaosException It does, but IQueryable implements IEnumrable

Comment: @Oskar: The where returns IQueryable and it does implement IEnumerable bu the results are not calculated. They pass to the server just after doing select or asenumerable so actually the order by you wrote made on the .net and not on the sql server.

Comment: @Oskar Kjellin: Thanks, What about the sorting with the name as second sort option?

Comment: @Naor, check now. You can use ThenBy

Comment: @Oskar Kjellin: You are the best.

Comment: @Oskar Kjellin: Do you know a way I can wrap SqlFunctions into my business layer (it doesn't have reference to System.data)?

Comment: @Naor Not sure, but I think an extension method might work. Define the extension method in your data layer. Make it return IQueryable<Customer> and be an extension of that class. The only way I can think of if you don't want to add a reference to System.Data

Comment: @Naor Something like: public static IQueryable<Customer> MyCustomSort(this IQueryable<Customer> customers)
        { return customers.OrderBy(x=> SqlFunctions.IsNumeric(x.customer_name)).
        ThenBy(x=> x.customer_name);

Comment: @Oskar: I intended to say the same as Naor mentioned, but was not very expressive! The old version of IsNumeric implementation you had would be executed @ .NET end and would have resulted in a runtime exception! The version you have now is the correct one! Cheers ;-)

Comment: @Oskar Kjellin: Leave it.. I created an extention to string with your previous solution. I have deeper "problem" - all my repositories are in the business layer.

Comment: @Naor Hehe, then what's in your data layer?

Comment: @Oskar Kjellin: :) In the data layer I put an implementation to my IRepository and UnitOfWork. My business layer has BaseRepository<> class that uses structuremap to get the EF repository implementation, and for each entity in the business layer I created repository that inherit from BaseRepository so actually the business entities repositories are in the business layer. What do you think?

Comment: @Naor I would've put the entities in a "Common"-layer which has no dependencies. Then the data layer references the common-layer and contains the repositories. The business layer also references the common

Comment: @Oskar Kjellin: My entities are my business layer and yor advice still require to make a reference to System.data in order to use SqlFunctions.

Comment: @Naor No, I say that you would put the entities in a common layer and your repositories in the data layer. Then the data layer would in turn need System.Data

Comment: @Oskar Kjellin: There is no need to put the entities in common layer because the data layer has reference to the business entities. The reason I don't like to put the repositories in the data layer is because I don't want to update structuremap for each repository and there is an easy access to all repository operations.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SqlFunctions.IsNumeric in your query to map to IsNumeric in Sql Server.

Something along the lines of:

```
        var results = from c in customers
                      where c.companyId = companyId
                      orderby SqlFunctions.IsNumeric(c.customerName) == 1 ? 1 : 0, c.customerName
                      select new { c.customerId, c.customerName, c.customerCode };
```

Comment: Thanks, What about the sorting with the name as second sort option?

Answer (score 0):

First I think there something wrong with the SQL query in

```
WHERE   company_id=@company_id AND
```

why you added `AND` ?

you can achieve ISNUMERIC in Entity Framewwork only (not linq to sql) by using [SqlFunctions.IsNumeric](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions.isnumeric.aspx)

```
return CUstomers.GetQuery().
            Where(x => x.CompanyId == companyId).
            OrderBy(x => SqlFunctions.IsNumeric(x.customer_name)).
            ThenBy(x => x.customer_name);
```